# How to get Azure DevOps Build Pipeline using Visual Studio Build to build everything and ignore the .sqlproj?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

We're currently using Azure DevOps to build our SQL Server database objects using RedGate.  We want to move to using the Visual Studio Build task.  In Visual Studio I did create a database project and put all of the objects in it (tables, sprocs, functions, views, etc).  It builds successfully.  I've been told there is a way to build everything in the repository and ignore what's in the .sqlproj file.  Our desire is to be able to add new objects to the repo and not have to open the database project and add them to the project, just add them to the repo and run the build.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: I think your question is not "how to ignore the .sqlproj" but "how to automatically include source files in the build". Visual Studio (actually MSBuild) will build a solution or a project. Within a project folder with a project using the SDK style, source files will be included in the project without being explicitly added to the project. The .sqlproj project is probably a legacy style project. However, projects can be extended and customized. For example, the .sqlproject project can be modified to have a step that includes all *.sql files found in the project folder.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Ah, yes, that's a better way of saying what we're wanting to do: "Use MSBuild in our DevOps pipeline to build all files in the repo."  Any suggestions where to look at extending and customizing projects?  Thanks much, this is helpful!

Comment: The .sqlproj is an XML MSBuild file. You can open the file in a text editor. The document root element is `Project`. In a legacy style project, the `Project` element will probably have a namespace attribute, i.e. `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`. Does your .sqlproj file have the  namespace attribute? Whether the project is legacy or SDK style may make a difference. Also - [MSBuild Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes, it does have a namespace:
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

Comment: @JonathanDodds I think I found the answer.  In the .sqlproj file, in the ItemGroup, change it from having a Build Include line for every file to just one per folder using *.sql.  This worked: `<Build Include="Stored Procedures\*.sql" />`  In my testing, this built all .sql files in the folder.

Comment: `<Build Include="**\*.sql" />` will match .sql files in the project directory and sub-directories. The wildcards are documented in [Use wildcards to specify items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#use-wildcards-to-specify-items)